# Icon for Eclipse is not shown

Tags: icons, eclipse, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

The icon for Eclipse does not appear when the program is running - I just see a broken icon instead. How can I fix this?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 eclipse44
Terminal=false
Icon=eclipse
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

`$ gedit /home/vanh/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`

[image: Directory showing icon]

[image: Broken icon in Dock]

Comment: Does eclipse even run?  The `Exec=` line doesn't match where eclipse is.  It should be `~/WORK/jee-photon/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: Yes, eclipse still working good, but icon of it's is not shown. I was tried edit path `Exec=~/WORK/jee-photon/eclipse/eclipse` and still nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your `eclipse.desktop` launcher. In a `.desktop` file, you need to use full paths, `~` is not expanded. So change `~/...` to `/home/vanh/...`.

Secondly, as @Terrance [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053397/icon-for-eclipse-is-not-shown#comment1721831_1053397), the correct path to the executable should be `/home/vanh/WORK/jee-photon/eclipse/eclipse` instead of `/home/vanh/WORK/jee-photon/eclipse`.

Finally, add one `StartupWMClass=Eclipse` line to the `eclipse.desktop` file.

Now you should be able to launch Eclipse from "Activities" overview (or "Show Applications") and it should show the correct icon on Ubuntu dock.

Comment: I didn't think about StartupWMClass.  Nice catch!  =)